# How could i put a highcharts funnel to rotate 90deg

Tags: highcharts

I have to make a funnel chart with 90 deg rotate ,i just want to put it horizontal.

But i tried `[HighCharts]` with `chart.inverted` and `plotOptions.funnel.reversed`, these are doesn't work.

Then i changed to  `[amChart]`, i tried `[AmFunnelChart]`, find a property `rotate`,but it doesn't work too.

I just want a horizontal funnel chart to show on my web page...

Am i have to write it by my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported in HighCharts ([source](http://forum.highcharts.com/post100466.html?hilit=funnel%20orientation#p100466)), but you can always request a feature. To do so please post a suggestion on [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/), or vote for the ones that already registered.